# MySQL SELECT query with another SELECT

Tags: mysql, select

I have the next sql query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(v.p_sery, v.p_id) AS sery,
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM v where p_delivery_result = 1) AS delivery_count,
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM v where p_delivery_result = 2) AS ND1,
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM v where p_delivery_result = 3) AS ND2,
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM v where p_delivery_result = 4) AS ND3,
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM v where p_delivery_result = 5) AS ND4,
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM v where p_delivery_result = 6) AS ND5,
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM v where p_delivery_result = 7) AS ND6,
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM v where p_delivery_result = 8) AS ND7
FROM (
   SELECT p_sery, p_id, d.p_delivery_result 
   FROM registries AS a, registry_regulations r, delivery d
   WHERE a.p_id = r.registry_id AND d.p_id = r.regulation_id AND (SELECT 
   STR_TO_DATE(a.p_date_created, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-06-01')
) as v;
```

But this not working.
Error: `Table v doesn't exist`
What I do wrong?

I have this tables:
[image]

And I want get the count of one of the status in table delivery

Comment: Please include sample data and tell us what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Can you also include some sample data with expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the derived table from the context of a correlated subquery. Try this query instead:

```
SELECT CONCAT(v.p_sery, v.p_id) AS sery,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN p_delivery_result = 1 THEN 1 END) AS delivery_count,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN p_delivery_result = 2 THEN 1 END) AS ND1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN p_delivery_result = 3 THEN 1 END) AS ND2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN p_delivery_result = 4 THEN 1 END) AS ND3,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN p_delivery_result = 5 THEN 1 END) AS ND4,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN p_delivery_result = 6 THEN 1 END) AS ND5,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN p_delivery_result = 7 THEN 1 END) AS ND6,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN p_delivery_result = 8 THEN 1 END) AS ND7
FROM (
   SELECT p_sery, p_id, d.p_delivery_result 
   FROM registries AS a
   JOIN registry_regulations r ON a.p_id = r.registry_id 
   JOIN delivery d d.p_id = r.regulation_id
   WHERE STR_TO_DATE(a.p_date_created, '%Y-%m-%d') 
            BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-06-01') as v;
```

**Note:** Always uses modern, *explicit* `JOIN` syntax instead of old-fashioned, *implicit* syntax.

Answer (score 0):

just remove as before V

```
FROM (
   SELECT p_sery, p_id, d.p_delivery_result 
   FROM registries AS a, registry_regulations r, delivery d
   WHERE a.p_id = r.registry_id AND d.p_id = r.regulation_id AND (SELECT 
   STR_TO_DATE(a.p_date_created, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-06-01')
   )  v
```

Comment: If I removed as nothing change i have the same error. `Table v doesn't exist`

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos  Your query is work but in the result one row, and  I need the period of the p_date_created date

Comment: What did you meen? I use MySQL

Comment: @ElSalvadore You should add your comment to my answer